# Chromium progress bar for Unity

Tags: chromium

I remember reading about a Unity progress bar for Chromium. In 12.04, I have the latest Chromium installed from the Software Centre, but it doesn't have a progress bar.

Is there one that can be installed / added?

Answer (score 3):

This was on the latest daily builds, it's not official, yet.
As http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/chromium-daily-adds-unity-progress-bar points out, you can download and install that build from https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa

Comment: This PPA hasn't been updated for 12.04.

Comment: @BasharatSial It's only a matter of time.

Comment: It should work if you hack the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chromium-daily-ppa.list (or whatever it's called) so that it points to something like oneiric or natty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the progress bar, you have to symlink the latest libunity.so-file to version 6.
For that you would `cd /usr/lib` and then `sudo ln -s libunity.so.9.0.2 libunity.so.6`. You might have to replace 9.0.2 with 9.0.1 or a different version that you have installed. The integration should then be available again.

I retrieved this information from [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102792#c16).

Answer (score 0):

Go to /usr/lib: Run the command in terminal:

`cd /usr/lib`

Create a symbolic link libunity.so.6 to the already existing symbolic link libunity.so.9, so whenever someone tries to access libunity.so.6, it will automatically redirect it to libunity.so.9. No need to know which version you have installed, 9.0.2 or 9.0.1. Run the command in terminal:

`ln -s libunity.so.9 libunity.so.6`